# I am using JWPlayer with a YouTube RSS Feed but it only shows 25 videos

Tags: video, joomla, youtube-api, limit, jwplayer

I am using JWPlayer with a YouTube RSS Feed but it only shows 25 videos. Is there anyway to get it to show more/all the videos?

I am requesting 50 videos from youtube (which does seem to show up in the RSS feed) but it doesn't show up in JWPlayer...

Here is the playlist:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLXvUy6gAtg0IxS4IdUCS6XSPq0FYQPv8E?max-results=50

Comment: Where is this running?

Comment: @EthanLongTail Oops, I thought I mentioned that. Its running on Joomla 2.5.1 and I'm using the free module.

Comment: @EthanLongTail http://bit.ly/16h0GpU

Comment: It looks like YouTube's default limit is 25 in their API, and the Max # is 50. http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/12920/a-25-videos-limit-in-youtube-playlist/

Comment: I know that. But only 25 are showing and I am requesting 50 "50?max-results=50"  All the videos are showing up in the RSS feed but they aren't showing up in JWPlayer

Comment: Try this - http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLXvUy6gAtg0IxS4IdUCS6XSPq0FYQPv8E?max-results=50&alt=rss

Comment: @EthanLongTail Its still only showing 25...

Comment: It looks like you will have to use php to do this, using the code provided by noone on the forum link above...